# Can you modify VisualSVN so that it renders HTML files?

Tags: svn, mime-types, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

We use SVN at work and have a VisualSVN server that everyone can use to see the structure of a repos. But when you look at a file it just shows it as text, which is good I guess, but we want to change it so that it actually renders the HTML or shows the image. Can this be done somehow? A wild quess is that is has to do with the MIME types or something of the files?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can!

You can apply *svn:mime-type* property *text/html* on a HTML file and web-browser will render it as HTML. The same works for other file types, e.g. *image/jpeg* for *.jpg image.

See http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/properties/ and http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/props/file-portability/#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type

Comment: What about the use of remote JavaScript? I write my documentation using [strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com/), with a mime type of `text/html` and in the HTML, I source a remote JS file. A local JS reference works fine, but not a remote one.

Comment: I don't remember what my problem had been at the time, but it might have had to do with insecure script sources. I think I had to switch them to https equivalents of the CDNs.